# xhtml & html, are there more differences than just the syntax?

Tags: html, xhtml

I have to hand in a thesis at the university where I have to create a website in xhtml.
We are not allowed to deliver this file in Html 5.

Since all the youtube tutorials and almost all forums only explain about html5, my question is. If I save the file in xhtml and follow the syntax correctly, can I also use every command that is available in html5?
Or are there other restrictions?

I thank you in advance for all replies.

I have to hand in a thesis at the university where I have to create a website in xhtml.
We are not allowed to deliver this file in Html 5.

Since all the youtube tutorials and almost all forums only explain about html5, my question is. If I save the file in xhtml and follow the syntax correctly, can I also use every command that is available in html5?
Or are there other restrictions?

Comment: The only element that's valid in HTML and invalid in XHTML is `<noscript>`. Otherwise, yes, it's just a syntax thing. It MUST be served with an "application/xhtml+xml" or "application/xml" mime type though.

Answer (score -1):

A XHTML page includes some strict elements and is a more strict and standardized version of HTML, with a syntax that follows the rules of XML - that's what makes it different from an HTML page. For instance, all elements must be in lowercase, empty elements must be closed with a closing slash, and attribute values must be quoted. Also, XHTML requires the use of Unicode encoding (UTF-8 or UTF-16).

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My XHTML Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to My XHTML Page</h1>
    <p>This is an example of an XHTML page. It follows the syntax rules of XML and is more strict than HTML.</p>
    <ul>
        <li>All elements must be properly nested and closed.</li>
        <li>All attributes must be quoted.</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Here are some examples of strict elements that are required in XHTML but not in HTML:</p>
    <ul>
        <li>All elements must be in lowercase.</li>
        <li>Empty elements must be closed with a closing slash (e.g., '<br />').</li>
        <li>Attribute values must be quoted (e.g., 'href="http://example.com"').</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Here is an example of a strict XHTML form:</p>
    <form action="http://example.com/submit" method="post">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        <br />
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Bottom-line: Yes, you can use most HTML5 elements and attributes in an XHTML document.